# What strong conditions could I include when deleting an exam

Tags: php, sql

I want admins and teachers to be able to delete exams if they wish to do so. Below are the steps to delete the exam:

- Admin can delete any exam
- A teacher con only delete exams which they have created

But my supervisor has stated this below:

> Deletion is a very sensitive action for the examination data. Please
>   use it very carefully. Function can be achieved but with strong
>   conditional constrains.  Inactive is very sensible so that people will
>   not do stupid things.

What my question is that any web developers who have experience in creating an applicaton where they have deleted exams, what other constraints should I follw if any? I allow teachers and admin to inactivate and activate exams by setting the "Active" column in the db to either "1" (active) or "0" (inactivate). But I also want them to delete exams if they wish.

Thank you

Comment: This is business logic; what you do is very much dependent on your organization's requirements, and even the law in some cases. I don't think we can help you much - we can advise, but your architect will have the final word.

Comment: Sorry guys  if you don't like the question but the 2 answers below has really helped me and shows that I should not delete anything when creating exams and hopefully future users who are making an exam system can look at this and realise exams should not be deleted. I will stick to what I am currently doing which is make exams active and inactive so when a student takes an eam, they can only see an active exam. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see people are not very happy with your question.
But I would say that I think I understand your problem.
I would NOT delete anything. Simply make records visible or invisible, so in case someone makes a mistake and deletes something, it will not be permanent.
Of course, whenever you list exams, you need to list only these that are visible.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would do what you stated and simply make exams active and inactive, thank you :)

Comment: Not to mention deleting rows that have foreign keys in relational databases can be a bit of a pickle. Inactive does mean all your other queries need to check that column, lest a report (for instance) shows 100 passes this year, but it was actually 90 and 10 for an inactive exam. This would be data that is not questioned and the mistake hardly visible without prior knowledge of the real data.

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER** delete anything (and particularly in your case) I'd even log who attempted the DELETE - Just mark them as un-viewable in your code. Otherwise referred to as an 'audit trail' and you'll thank StackOverflow later!

Comment: I know I can ony give one best answer so I gave the other answer the best answer and gave you the upvote, if would of marked both answers as best answers if it was possible

Comment: That's ok - How honest. Glad to hear you have such qualities! Good luck with your implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with many people here. You should not delete an exam unless it has no content.
You can, though, set 2 new columns in your exams table:

1. `date_deleted` default NULL, datatype DATETIME
2. `deleted_by` default NULL, datatype INT (FK to user id who deletes it)

so you can make authorized users set the first value to `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` and second value to his/her user id. And make sure you're excluding so called deleted exams from your queries by a where clause like `WHERE ... AND date_deleted IS NULL` or `WHERE date_deleted IS NULL`.

First column above will do the main job. It will not only let you know that exam is deleted but it will also keep the date/time it was deleted. Second column, on the other hand, will let you know who took that action. I believe both will be beneficial in different situations.